# Are Galois conjugates of a prime of a cyclotomic ring also primes?

Tags: prime-numbers, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-fields, algebraic-numbers

For the sake of simplicity consider $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_{5}]$. If a cyclotomic integer $z\in\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{5}]$ is a prime of the integer ring, is it true that its Galois conjugates $\{z, \sigma_1(z), \sigma_2(z), \sigma_3(z)\}$ are primes as well?

If so, is this true more generally?

Comment: Galois conjugates of prime ideals are prime ideals; principal ideals are prime if and only if they are generated by primes. The Galois conjugate of a principal ideal is the principal ideal generated by the conjugate.

Comment: Galois automorphisms are automorphisms. What happens to a prime element under an automorphisms?

Answer (score 1):

If $R$ is a commutative unital ring, $p\in R$ is a prime element and $\sigma\in\operatorname{Aut}(R)$, then for all $a,b\in R$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sigma(p)\mid ab
\quad&\iff&\quad p\mid\sigma^{-1}(a)\sigma^{-1}(b)\\
\quad&\iff&\quad p\mid\sigma^{-1}(a)\ \vee\ p\mid\sigma^{-1}(b)\\
\quad&\iff&\quad \sigma(p)\mid a\ \vee\ \sigma(p)\mid b,
\end{eqnarray*}
which shows that $\sigma(p)$ is also prime